# Unresolved externals error during compilation

Tags: c++

I am getting two unresolved externals error while trying to compile the following c++ program in Visual Studio 2010- 
                 http://codepad.org/5ZS4gtfP

I tried cross checking everything but cant seem to find the problem. Can someone plz compile it in VS 2010 and try to find out the solution?

Comment: put code here please. codepad expires after some time.

Answer (score 3):

For a start, `conio.h` is not standard C or C++ - it tends to be found in code written for the Turbo C/C++ products, a particular favourite of Indian universities.

And they invariably use it just so they can call `getch` when there's a perfectly adequate `getchar` in the standard :-)

As to the `index` variable, it's probably already defined in one of the headers.

Comment: conio.h is supported by Visual C++ as well. I still commonly see it used in Windows programs - perhaps they don't really care about portability and/or standards. Then again, SO is not `comp.lang.c++`

Comment: The advice is to use `#include <iostream>` or at least `#include <cstdio>` in C++.

Comment: @Eli, "don't care about standards" isn't an excuse. Standards are made to be honored.

Comment: @ulidtko: note that my comment wasn't a justification, more a clarification

Answer (score 0):

- Line 18: error: conio.h: No such file or directory:

Try to include `<conio.h>` instead of `"conio.h"`.

- Line 25: error: 'unsigned int index' redeclared as different kind of symbol:

It could be that one of the headers you're including already declares `index`. Try to rename it to see the difference - or better yet don't use a global variable at all.

Comment: `index` is a non-standard function found in some implementations of `<string.h>` (or `<strings.h>`, where deprecated functions such as this tend to live these days)

Comment: @Paul R: Interesting, I didn't know that.

Comment: From the `index` man page HISTORY section: *"The index() and rindex() functions appeared in Version 6 AT&T UNIX.  Their prototypes existed previously in <string.h> before they were moved to <strings.h> for IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 (``POSIX.1'') compliance."*